# Raytracing: hit areas & incident angles

Tags: windows, 3d

folks!

I am looking for 3d ray-tracing software that fits the following criteria:

- Reads common 3d formats and is able to tag/name the objects (the objects in question are buildings in a city)
- I'm only interested in direct line-of-sight "views". It does not need to support optical behaviors like reflection, refraction, scattering or diffraction. That is, one can think all the objects in the environment are fully absorbent.
- As an output, I'm not interested in the rendered image but "**illuminated areas**" (polygons) and corresponding 3-dimensional **incident angles** (azimuth and elevation) from a single, isotropic (light) source (which, in our application, is not light). That is, which areas of which objects (buildings) get illuminated by this (light) source, and what is the 3d incident angle of the rays.
- The 3d incident angle naturally depends on the actual location within the illuminated area. Ideally, the software would return a list with illuminated polygons for each object (building), and by giving a place on that polygon (say, the geometric center), it would find the incident angle (azimuth and elevation).
- Licensing: Fit for commercial use.
- Budget: No restrictions.
- OS: Ideally Windows, but Ubuntu would also work.
- UI: Ideally command line/terminal, but GUI would also work.

Thank you.